# Nav walker, bootstrap: Display 3rd level items under 2nd level

Tags: menus, walker, sub-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the WP_bootstrap_navwalker for  a dropdown menu. This works fine, but it only shows me the first and second level items. So de dropdown on the first level and a regular second item when dropdown is open. The third level is not visible.

I want to display it under my second level items. The walker is now making it an other dropdown (it does not work).

I am not skilled enough to properly edit the walker to fit make it fit my needs. can anyone help me?

The walker code:

```
class wp_bootstrap_navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
/**
 * @see Walker::start_lvl()
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param int $depth Depth of page. Used for padding.
 */
public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul role=\"menu\" class=\" dropdown-menu\">\n";
}
/**
 * @see Walker::start_el()
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param object $item Menu item data object.
 * @param int $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
 * @param int $current_page Menu item ID.
 * @param object $args
 */
public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    /**
     * Dividers, Headers or Disabled
     * =============================
     * Determine whether the item is a Divider, Header, Disabled or regular
     * menu item. To prevent errors we use the strcasecmp() function to so a
     * comparison that is not case sensitive. The strcasecmp() function returns
     * a 0 if the strings are equal.
     */
    if ( strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'divider' ) == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="divider">';
    } else if ( strcasecmp( $item->title, 'divider') == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="divider">';
    } else if ( strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'dropdown-header') == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">' . esc_attr( $item->title );
    } else if ( strcasecmp($item->attr_title, 'disabled' ) == 0 ) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="disabled"><a href="#">' . esc_attr( $item->title ) . '</a>';
    } else {
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        if ( $args->has_children )
            $class_names .= ' dropdown';
        if ( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes ) )
            $class_names .= ' active';
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';
        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->title )   ? $item->title  : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )  ? $item->target : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )     ? $item->xfn    : '';
        // If item has_children add atts to a.
        if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
            $atts['href']           = '#';
            $atts['data-toggle']    = 'dropdown';
            $atts['class']          = 'dropdown-toggle';
            $atts['aria-haspopup']  = 'true';
        } else {
            $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
        }
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );
        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }
        $item_output = $args->before;
        /*
         * Glyphicons
         * ===========
         * Since the the menu item is NOT a Divider or Header we check the see
         * if there is a value in the attr_title property. If the attr_title
         * property is NOT null we apply it as the class name for the glyphicon.
         */
        if ( ! empty( $item->attr_title ) )
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span class="glyphicon ' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . '"></span>&nbsp;';
        else
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= ( $args->has_children && 0 === $depth ) ? ' <span class="caret"></span></a>' : '</a>' ;
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
/**
 * Traverse elements to create list from elements.
 *
 * Display one element if the element doesn't have any children otherwise,
 * display the element and its children. Will only traverse up to the max
 * depth and no ignore elements under that depth.
 *
 * This method shouldn't be called directly, use the walk() method instead.
 *
 * @see Walker::start_el()
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param object $element Data object
 * @param array $children_elements List of elements to continue traversing.
 * @param int $max_depth Max depth to traverse.
 * @param int $depth Depth of current element.
 * @param array $args
 * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @return null Null on failure with no changes to parameters.
 */
public function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, &$output ) {
    if ( ! $element )
        return;
    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
    // Display this element.
    if ( is_object( $args[0] ) )
       $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[ $element->$id_field ] );
    parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
}
/**
 * Menu Fallback
 * =============
 * If this function is assigned to the wp_nav_menu's fallback_cb variable
 * and a manu has not been assigned to the theme location in the WordPress
 * menu manager the function with display nothing to a non-logged in user,
 * and will add a link to the WordPress menu manager if logged in as an admin.
 *
 * @param array $args passed from the wp_nav_menu function.
 *
 */
public static function fallback( $args ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        extract( $args );
        $fb_output = null;
        if ( $container ) {
            $fb_output = '<' . $container;
            if ( $container_id )
                $fb_output .= ' id="' . $container_id . '"';
            if ( $container_class )
                $fb_output .= ' class="' . $container_class . '"';
            $fb_output .= '>';
        }
        $fb_output .= '<ul';
        if ( $menu_id )
            $fb_output .= ' id="' . $menu_id . '"';
        if ( $menu_class )
            $fb_output .= ' class="' . $menu_class . '"';
        $fb_output .= '>';
        $fb_output .= '<li><a href="' . admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) . '">Add a menu</a></li>';
        $fb_output .= '</ul>';
        if ( $container )
            $fb_output .= '</' . $container . '>';
        echo $fb_output;
    }
}
```

}

Sorry for my English, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem. follow these instructions.....

1. Add script

   ```
   (function($){
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
           event.preventDefault(); 
           event.stopPropagation(); 
           $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
           $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
       });
   }); 
   })(jQuery);
   ```

2.Remove `&& $depth === 0`
from this line: `if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 )` in `wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php` file.

See the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZnOU.png).

Comment: do the steps as your answer, but still not working. carret is showing in the second level menu. but the third level menu is not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove the

```
&& 0 === $depth
```

on the line

```
$item_output .= ( $args->has_children && 0 === $depth ) ? ' <span class="caret"></span></a>' : '</a>';
```

so the carret will be shown beside the text on your menu.

Comment: do the steps as your answer, but still not working. carret is showing in the second level menu. but the third level menu is not displaying.

Comment: I can confirm that the answers listed here are not working too. I am trying to figure out the same thing on a newer version of the nav walker.

Answer (score 1):

For those still searching for an answer, I found a solution.

This method just uses a custom class to target the second level dropdowns and toggle the Boostrap `.show` class on the second level dropdowns.

1) In the WP Dashboard Menus section set the second level dropdown link to an `href="#"`.

2) Set a custom class to `dropdown-sub`.

3) Add this to your js:

```
$('.dropdown-sub', this).click(function(e){
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).toggleClass('show');
})

//This is to stop the Bootstrap menu from closing when a link is clicked.
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

4) Add this to your css:

```
.dropdown-sub a[href$='#']:after {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: .255em;
    vertical-align: .255em;
    content: "";
    border-top: .3em solid;
    border-right: .3em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: .3em solid transparent;
}
}
```

Step 4 is just to add the carat to the end of the second level dropdown.

You shouldn't need to modify the navwalker with this method.

Comment: I know this an old answer but this worked for me. The depth of menu items is set in wp_nav_menu itself. The issue here is that the third level items dont show. Ive targeted them specifically with .menu-item-has-children .menu-item-has-children.dropdown so the third level opens when clicked. Thanks Nick!